# Unable to find any JVMs matching architecture "x86_64". No Java runtime present, try --request to install. No Java runtime present, requesting install

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, terminal, osx-yosemite

while launching eclipse from the terminal I get this error
Unable to find any JVMs matching architecture "x86_64". No Java runtime present, try --request to install. No Java runtime present, requesting install
thank you

Comment: So did you try `--request`?

Comment: Sounds you need to download and install a 64 bit JDK and set your JAVA_HOME to point to it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Re-check your Java version by `java -version` and make sure that it matches your Mac's architecture and $JAVA_HOME points to correct version.

If you *do* have correct Java version installed, maybe [that's](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4351927?start=0&tstart=0) some kind of a bug.

Answer (score 0):

If Miu's above suggestion didn't work - see MrDev's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44009058/even-though-jre-8-is-installed-on-my-mac-no-java-runtime-present-requesting-t) that indicates that what is needed is the Java JDK rather than JRE.