# Even though JRE 8 is installed on my MAC -" No Java Runtime present,requesting to install " gets displayed in terminal

Tags: java, xamarin

Even though  JRE 8  is installed on my MAC OS Yosemite 10.10.3,while running the Android present in tools in  sdk - the error - " No Java Runtime present,requesting to install " gets displayed in terminal- how do i solve this issue?

1. I wanted to install Xamarin test recorder - after installing they
   asked me to install Android sdk
2. SDK is downloaded in Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk
3. Now when I run Android present in tools folder - I get the error -
   No Java run time
4. I've installed JRE 8 with get the verified
   java version from their site

Can someone please help!!

Comment: What happens if you type "java -version" into the terminal?

Comment: What happens if you type `echo $JAVA_HOME` into the terminal?

Comment: @BobDalgleish the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` does not need to exist.

Comment: You need to install the jdk, not only the jre

Comment: This probably belongs on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: @abalos same error - No Java runtime present  - requesting to install

Comment: @MauroPiccotti yes i have installed the jdk ..its in the path /Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk/ path

Comment: to install a specific version ie for 11 version with homebrew `brew install openjdk@11` and then for setting the path `sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk`

Answer (score 242, accepted):

You have to install the full JDK, not only the JRE.

I had the same issue and solved by installing JDK.

Please use [this link](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/) to download the latest JDK version 21.

Comment: I got this error while adding Debug signing certificate SHA-1 keys to firebase ,for mac just download the mac os installer and install it once done, and run the command debug certificate generation command and it works

Comment: yes, you have to install JDK within your Mac OS to get rid of this error.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem for the latest JDK on macOS 10.15.7.

Comment: This solution didnot work for Monterey (12.4). after installing JDK also $JAVA_HOME is empty

Answer (score 177):

After installing openjdk with brew and runnning `brew info openjdk` I got this:

```
==> openjdk: stable 21 (bottled) [keg-only]
Development kit for the Java programming language
https://openjdk.java.net/
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/21 (600 files, 331MB)
  Poured from bottle using the formulae.brew.sh API on 2023-09-26 at 11:06:55
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/o/openjdk.rb
License: GPL-2.0-only with Classpath-exception-2.0
==> Dependencies
Build: autoconf ✔, pkg-config ✔
Required: giflib ✔, harfbuzz ✔, jpeg-turbo ✔, libpng ✔, little-cms2 ✔
==> Requirements
Build: Xcode (on macOS) ✘
Required: macOS >= 10.15 (or Linux) ✔
==> Caveats
For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with
  sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk

openjdk is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew,
because macOS provides similar software and installing this software in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have openjdk first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find openjdk you may need to set:
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/include"
```

And from that I got this command here, and after running it I got Java working

```
sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk
```

Comment: Running in macOS 10.15.7 Catalina, I additionally needed to set my PATH.

Comment: Yes! Bang on. I guess it's as simple as "RTFI"

Comment: Can you elaborate @ChaimLeibHalbert?

Comment: This is for me the best solution to this issue.

Comment: That solves the issue. Thanks :)

Comment: This: `sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk`

Comment: Thanks!
Running on macOS Monterey - 12.4  
1- brew install openjdk@11  
2- echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc  
3- sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk

Comment: Same as @Cem.  brew install openjdk@17.  Did the symlink and then added the path.  perfect!

Comment: By default, homebrew is using a new directory structure now. The command now should be `sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk`

Comment: This is really close. java --version
openjdk 11.0.17 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 11.0.17+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 11.0.17+0, mixed mode)

javaws ~/Downloads/iLO-jirc.jnlp
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.

Answer (score 136):

## 2021 solution

### TL;DR

```sh
brew install temurin
```

### Details

On an M1 Mac/Apple Silicon (running Big Sur), I had already `openjdk` installed. As signaled in a previous answer by Mohammed, `openjdk` is keg-only with `brew`, and hence requires [adding a symlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62702800/4855849).

After following this, it solved the `No Java Runtime present` error, but `rJava` was complaining about missing `libjvm.dylib` and that existing libraries were for the wrong architecture:

```
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(jvm, FALSE)
  error: unable to load shared object '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/16.0.2/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib':
  dlopen(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/16.0.2/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib, 10): 
    no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/16.0.2/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib: 
    mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Installing [Eclipse **Temurin**](https://adoptium.net/) (previously `AdoptOpenJDK`) (and removing the previously created symlink in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk`) immediately solved both issues seamlessly.

Just run `brew install temurin` and everything should be OK.

Comment: sh: command not found: brew

Comment: @EugeneTroyanskii: https://brew.sh/ → Install Homebrew (package manager on macOS)

Comment: This is the only working solution

Answer (score 83):

I didn't need the full JDK, I just needed to make JRE work and none of the other answers provided above worked for me. 
Maybe it used to work, but now (1st Jul 2018) it isn't working. I just kept getting the error and the pop-up.

I eventually solved this issue by placing the following JAVA_HOME export in ~/.bash_profile:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

Hope this helps someone.
I'm running Mac OS High Sierra.

Comment: I'm also on High Sierra and unfortunately this did work, although it "fixed" the error message "No Java Runtime present". I got this, then: "Could not find tools.jar. Please check that /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home contains a valid JDK installation."

Answer (score 77):

I just had to do the following on Mac:

```
brew install openjdk
sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home"
java --version
```

Comment: You can `export JAVA_HOME="/usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home"`. No need for symlink.

Comment: @nakamume Symlink is recommended by Homebrew

Comment: even better the second line: 
`sudo ln -sfn $(brew --prefix)/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk`

Comment: How I can save this result after restarting macOS?

Comment: @Valeriy add `export JAVA_HOME="..."` to your Bash or ZSH profile

Answer (score 31):

If you came across the error when tried to **generate a jks file (keystore)**, so try adding

```
/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/keytool
```

before running the command, like so:

```
/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
```

Answer (score 18):

working by following command

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home"
```

Comment: I just run it at Android Studio Terminal and works like a charm, Thanks

Comment: didnt help for my case

Comment: so open path manually from finder and go until you found jre and copy relative path and export it, like Application=>Android studio=>

Comment: For newer versions of Android Studio:
export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/

Answer (score 16):

Since it sounds like your JAVA_HOME variable is not set correctly, follow the instructions for setting that.

[Setting JAVA_HOME environment variable on MAC OSX 10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842743/setting-java-home-environment-variable-on-mac-osx-10-9)

I would imagine once you set this, it will stop complaining.

Comment: This is the correct answer -- it is enough to install JRE and set JAVA_HOME to make Java command available in shell.

Answer (score 14):

Maybe someone is still having the same issue. You can install openjdk using homebrew, and then add the new JDK `bin` directory to the front of your path:

```
cd ~

brew install openjdk

echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"' >> .bash_profile

source .bash_profile
```

Comment: In my case installed openjdk location was `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/17.0.1_1/bin`

Answer (score 14):

**Pre-Requisite:**

- I already had java11 installed on my machine using brew.

Step-1: `brew info java11`

output:

**/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@11**

```
USER1-MacBook-Pro JavaVirtualMachines % brew info java11
openjdk@11: stable 11.0.12 (bottled) [keg-only]
Development kit for the Java programming language
https://openjdk.java.net/
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.12 (670 files, 273.0MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2021-10-09 at 13:07:04
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/openjdk@11.rb
License: GPL-2.0-only
==> Dependencies
Build: autoconf ✔
==> Requirements
Build: Xcode ✘
==> Caveats
For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with
  sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk

openjdk@11 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew,
because this is an alternate version of another formula.

If you need to have openjdk@11 first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find openjdk@11 you may need to set:
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/include"

==> Analytics
install: 44,188 (30 days), 149,578 (90 days), 433,845 (365 days)
install-on-request: 19,074 (30 days), 63,262 (90 days), 187,286 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

Step-2: Append openJDK path to existing path.

echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

Step-3: Source existing shell or open new terminal to validate changes

- `source ~/.zshrc`

Step-4: Check path is added

- `which java`

output: `/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/bin/java`

Step-5:

- `java --version`

```java
openjdk 11.0.12 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 11.0.12+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 11.0.12+0, mixed mode)
```

Comment: It helped me kind of, but after this, I can't run Homebrew: `zsh: command not found: brew`

Answer (score 8):

I solved the problem by installing `oracle-sdk` with `brew`.

```
brew install oracle-jdk --cask
```

Answer (score 6):

## TL;DR

#### For JDK 11 try this:

To handle this problem in a clean way, I suggest to use `brew` and `jenv`.

#### **For Java 11** follow this 2 steps, first :

```
JAVA_VERSION=11
brew reinstall jenv 
brew reinstall openjdk@${JAVA_VERSION}
jenv add /usr/local/opt/openjdk@${JAVA_VERSION}/
jenv global ${JAVA_VERSION}
```

#### And add this at end of your shell config scripts 
`~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`

```
export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(jenv init -)"
export JAVA_HOME="$HOME/.jenv/versions/`jenv version-name`"
```

## Problem solved!

Then restart your shell and try to execute `java -version`

Note: If you have this problem, your current JDK version is not existent or misconfigured (or may be you have only JRE).

Comment: `java -version` works for me, but `apt` can't find it. For example, when I do `apt update` I get the error `The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports apt.`

Comment: Are you trying to run this on MacOS?

Comment: Yes running on BigSur

Comment: But AFAIK `apt` is not available on MacOS

Comment: as always, the instructions don't work.  when I try the first jenv (after the brew installs), I get the error: "ln: /Users/ekkis/.jenv/versions/openjdk64-11.0.10: No such file or directory"

Comment: @ekkis very likely you were already using jenv, in any case double check your jenv defaults and what's in `/Users/ekkis/.jenv/versions/`

Comment: the directory you mention is empty

Comment: @ekkis you have to execute `jenv add ...` first

Answer (score 6):

**In 2022:**

No need to download Java anymore, once Android Studio is installed.

Even though Java 11 is embedded with Android Studio now, on Mac sometimes this problem arises and the Java runtime is not found.

So, I have solved this problem by doing these two steps:

1. In Android Studio go to File > Project Structure. If, under the SDK entry, you can see there is no default SDK selected, but a text in red "No SDK", click on it and you will find an SDK / JDK list, select one of them. Thats it.
2. Make sure you run Android Studio from Application Folder.
   For this copy the Android Studio launcher to the Application folder. Then in the Finder, go to the Application folder.  Right-click on it. Click on "Show package contents", then navigate up to jre folder. Copy the folder and paste it into your home folder.

Now setup the path from the terminal: you can create a folder named  java_jre, and the path must be set to `jre/contents/Home` :

```
Noors-Mac-mini:bin noorhossain$ export JAVA_HOME="/Users/noorhossain/java_jre/jre/Contents/Home"
```

// now checking the version :

```
Noors-Mac-mini:bin noorhossain$ java -version

openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 6):

**In 2022, only if Android studio is installed:**

1. Check if JDK is installed in Android studio. In Android Studio go to File > Project Structure. Under the SDK entry, if there is no default JDK selected, select from the list, or if there isn't any, add JDK and then apply to install.
2. After the JDK is installed in Android studio, you just need to add the JDK path directly from your Android Studio. Run the below command in the terminal and that's it.

> ```
> echo 'export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home"' >> ~/.zshrc
> ```

3. Now, check if it's working.

> ```
> ❯ java -version
> openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763, mixed mode)
> ```

***No need to install any package from brew or create any symlink. The Java is already embedded with the Android studio and we can use this directly for our system.***

Answer (score 4):

In newer versions of OS X (especially Yosemite, EL Capitan), Apple has removed Java support for security reasons.
To fix this you have to do the following.

1. Download Java for OS X 2015-001 from this link: https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572?locale=en_US
2. Mount the disk image file and install Java 6 runtime for OS X.

   After this you should not be seeing any of the below messages:

   *- Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)"*

   *- No Java runtime present, try --request to install.*

   This should resolve the issue for the pop-up shown below:
   [image]

Comment: But that is a super old Java. Installing it is a security risk as it is not updated any more.

Answer (score 3):

## Error

### error terminal when try to find java version:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.

abdallahandroid@Abdallah-mahmoud ~ % java -version
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

### error when try to run "flutter doctor"

```
Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
```

## try to fix by using "brew"

1- install homebrew :

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

2- install java by brew

```
abdallahandroid@Abdallah-mahmoud ~ % brew install java
```

3- set export pat

```
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"
```

case set forever by using editior " vim /etc/paths "

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/bin
```

must restart sometime the mac itself !!, some time not just need to restart termnial

4- test installation

```
java -version
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is worked for me on macos mojave 10.14.6 version

I installed current jdk(https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html)

Then do respectively;

- vim .bash_profile
- add "export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" to bash_profile
- source .bash_profile

it is done. And you can check the version with java -version command.

Answer (score 2):

If you  are having this issue for the same reason that I am, I can tell you why it is happening. I just don't know how to fix it yet.

Here it is:

I am using JDK version 1.8 on MacOS Big Sur.  I do not want to have to install a later version of the JDK because all my projects run on 1.8. But here's the thing.... On the command line

```
java -version
```

Returns this:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_302"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_302-bre_2021_08_14_21_34-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.302-b00, mixed mode)
```

but a slightly different command (version prefixed with 2 dashes instead of 1)

```
java --version
```

returns this error:

```
Unrecognized option: --version
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

This is because Java 8 uses single dash version, all JDKs after use double dash.

So the machine, when looking for JAVA_HOME, is also using double dashes and getting the error.

Answer (score 2):

just run this

```
sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk
```

Answer (score 1):

I have Mojave 10.14.6 and the only thing that did work for me was:

- setting JAVA_HOME to the following:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

- source .bash_profile (or wherever you keep your vars, in my case .zshrc)

Hope it helps! You can now type `java --version` and it should work

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that with my current version of SQLDeveloper (`21.2.1`), there's another way to specify the JDK location. In my case, I was able to open up `~/.sqldeveloper/21.2.1/product.conf` and set the `JavaHome` directive to the appropriate directory. I use `jabba` for JDK version management, and this path was something like `~/.jabba/jdk/amazon-corretto@1.8.292-10.1/Contents/Home`. Needless to say, just setting that config value and restarting SQLDeveloper left me with a running copy again. This should work with any version of SQLDeveloper given the `product.conf` file exists inside your user's `.sqldeveloper` directory appropriate for the version you are using.

Answer (score -3):

install JDK it will work ,

here is the jdk link to download .

link: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk13-downloads- 
   5672538.html