# pyimagej setup + conda: No Java runtime present, requesting install

Tags: java, python, java-8, imagej, miniconda

**Problem**

I'm trying to use pyimagej==0.4.0 ([source](https://github.com/imagej/pyimagej)).  Per its README, I run the following code:

```
import imagej
ij = imagej.init()
```

And it returns the following error: `No Java runtime present, requesting install.`

I looked up this error in multiple articles:

- [Even though JRE 8 is installed on my MAC -" No Java Runtime present,requesting to install " gets displayed in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44009058/11163122)
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/283858/327668

Both articles say I need the full JDK, not just the JRE.  However, I think I have the full JDK.

**Background**

- `pyimagej==0.4.0`
- `macOS Mojave v10.14.3`
- `miniconda 4.6.14`

Set up conda environment with:

1. `conda create -n pyimagej pyimagej openjdk=8`
2. `conda activate pyimagej`

Checking environment:

```
(pyimagej) ➜  fiji_test java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_192"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.33.0.1-macosx) (build 1.8.0_192-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.33.0.1-macosx) (build 25.192-b01, mixed mode)
(pyimagej) ➜  fiji_test echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/pyimagej
```

Can you please fill in what am I missing?  Thank you in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out the problem was quite in the weeds.

It seems this problem was encountered by one of `pyimagej`'s developers here: https://github.com/imagej/pyimagej/issues/10

The developer posed a short-term workaround of directly modifying the jdk's `Info.plist`.

The developer also opened a PR for a more long-term solution.  Hopefully it gets closed, and then hopefully no one else will encounter this!  :)