# JDK is installed on mac but i'm getting "The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports apt." sudo apt update

Tags: java, terminal, apt

I'm trying to run the command `sudo apt update` on my terminal in MacOS

I'm getting this message in response: `The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports apt. Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.`

I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44009058/even-though-jre-8-is-installed-on-my-mac-no-java-runtime-present-requesting-t), however even though I made sure to install the JDK like the solution suggested I'm still getting the same response.

I also tried pasting

```
export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(jenv init -)"
export JAVA_HOME="$HOME/.jenv/versions/`jenv version-name`"
```

Into my .zshrc.save folder and had no luck.

When I run `java -version` in the terminal this is what I get back:

```
java version "15.0.2" 2021-01-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.2+7-27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.2+7-27, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Maybe it is getting confused with the old path of jdk. Did you delete the old the jdk or at least removed it from the path and JAVA_HOME.

Comment: For clarity, a comment on a now-deleted answer shows that OP is trying to follow https://phoenixnap.com/kb/update-node-js-version which is a guide for linux, and the `apt` they mention is referring to debian/ubuntu package manager, not java's annotation processing tool.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

20 years ago, java shipped with a tool called `apt`: Annotation Processor Tool. This tool was obsolete not much later.

What that update-node-js-version is talking about, is **a completely and totally unrelated tool**: It's the `Advanced Package Tool`, which is a tool to manage installations **on debian and ubuntu** - linux distros. You do not **want** to run this on a mac, and the instructions you found are therefore completely useless: That is how to update node-js on linux. Your machine isn't linux.

Search around for answers involving `brew`, which is the go-to equivalent of `apt` on mac. And completely forget about java - this has NOTHING to do with java - that was just a pure coincidence.

Comment: Thanks! That makes so much more sense now. For reference to anybody who didn't see earlier I was trying to follow this tutorial: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/update-node-js-version

Comment: How do we use brew to do it instead of sudo apt?

Comment: The question does not mention what 'it' is, @FranciscoGutierrezRamirez

Comment: This is the answer I needed - was trying to use `sudo apt install certbot` stupidly and needed to use `brew install certbot` instead. Even Java can't name their stuff properly ‍♂️

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I don't think the debian team gets to just claim a 3-letter acronym. It was apple and linux distributions that decided to pile __every__ tool in a JDK's `bin` dir into your path which was never the intended design. Tragic, nobody is to blame for any of this however.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Agreed but these days, anyone saying `apt` will probably only think of the package manager, not the Java `apt` tool

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary That was true when oracle added 'apt' to the `bin` dir of OpenJDK distros too, but there are ~50 executables in there and we just do not name executables e.g. `org.openjdk.java-compiler-v16`. We name them `javac`. That's not OpenJDK's choosing. They didn't mess up this name. Nobody is individually 'at fault'.

Comment: ...uh...folks...all of the above and everything else here makes good sense.  But maybe someone can explain how THIS fits into it all:  https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/apt

Comment: ugh thank you for this context!! this is exactly what i needed to know

Comment: @CryptoFool `apt` is an executable that does things. Specifically, it lets you interact with apt repositories. On its own it is useless unless you add apt repo sources. __On linux__, it ships out of the box with useful repo sources pre-configured. apt repo sources exist with packages ready to install on e.g. debian linux distributions. `brew install apt` installs the tool. This is a completely useless tool without a repo. Sometimes folks make their own apt repos (it's open source after all). `brew install apt` is always entirely useless.

Comment: @rzwitserloot - I don't understand the point of your response to me.  I know exactly what "apt" is on a Debian-style Linux host, and I know that it is useless without its package repos.  I was asking what the purpose of the "apt" tool is that exists in Brew...that is, is there an appropriate use for this tool on a Mac?  Maybe I could have made my question clearer.  Telling me that it is completely useless doesn't answer my question as to why there is a build of the tool in Brew.

Comment: hmm, unfortunate typo, I meant to write '__almost__ entirely useless'. It's useful if you want to write and maintain your own mini apt repos. Hence the second-to-last-line: "Sometimes folks make their own apt repos".

Comment: OMG, I was so confused why the thing I was trying to do was talking about java... thanks so much for this answer.

Answer (score 5):

> Install Homebrew on your Mac Machine

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

> For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with

```
sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk
```

> If you need to have openjdk first in your PATH, run:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
```

> For compilers to find openjdk you may need to set:

```
 export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openjdk/include"
```

Answer (score 1):

The below commands worked for me.

First, install the homebrew

**`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`**

Then set the Android Studio Java path to the Home(If you have Android Studio). If not then you take the respective Java path & export it to the JAVA Home path.

**`export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home`**

Answer (score -1):

Use brew instead of sudo apt, if you're using Mac.